# Is there a single keystroke to go to the next reference to the current symbol?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Or a way to define one?

My poor workaround is SHIFT+F12 to find all current references, F8 repeated until desired reference is reached. But I would like a keypress that goes specifically to the next.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Control+Shift+Down Arrow` to move to the next highlighted reference. This executes the Edit.NextHighlighedReference command. Not quite the same as this only works in the currently open file, but it's close.

Comment: Close enough for me - thanks CN. OOI, in what way is it "not quite the same", apart from working in only the current file?

Comment: @ChrisJJ - That's the only diff I'm aware of. I'll update my answer, as it does seem like there's more than 1 difference :-)